# Changing scales and symbols in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting rows of two 4X10 Matrix d1, and d2 in one graph as follows:

```
plot(as.matrix(d1[2,]), as.matrix(d2[2,]), type="o", col="red", ann=FALSE) +
lines(as.matrix(d1[1,]),as.matrix(d2[1,]), type="o", col="blue", ann=FALSE)
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image]

Now I want to make some changes that I have failed to do so far:

1) Change the y-axis to log-scale. I cannot find the scale_y_log type of thing (exists in *ggplot*) in *plot* function.

2) Change the datapoint symbols for each line plot to be different (at the moment they are all circle). I tried to pass the *par* parameter's *pch*, but that changes things for all lines.

3) Forcing my own intervals to x-axis. For example instead 0,2,4,6,8 to have 0,0.5,1.5,2, 3, 4, 5, 10. I tried to find something similar to *ggplot* *scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,0.5,1.5,2, 3, 4, 5, 10))*, but failed to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example which you can adapt for your data

```
x_axis_labels <- c(0,0.5,1.5,2, 3, 4, 5, 10.)      # The x-axis labels you provided
plot(1:10, exp(c(1:10)), log = 'y', pch = 24)      # Plot of sample data, making y-axis log scale, and change points to triangles.
axis(1,labels = x_axis_labels, at = x_axis_labels) # Changing the x-axis labels
```

The above is not using a matrix, however, it seemed some of the main issue you are having is with the `log` plot and changing the point type.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The plot doesn't reflect the new labels. Is there a way to use log10 instead of loge when scaling?

Comment: @user3639557 I fixed the issue, I had uploaded the wrong jpeg.  This should be fixed now. Whether you are using `log(x, base = exp(1))` or `log(x, base = 10)`, the y values will only differ by a constant.  What output are you looking for ?  If you use `plot(x, 10^c(1:10), log = 'y', pch = 24)` instead, you will see the y-axis values change but the data shape stay the same.